# filename expansion not understood in bash

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOG="myfile.log"

ls -l "${LOG}_*"

find . -type f -name "${LOG}_*" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

which produces the following output:

```
$ ./test.sh

ls: cannot access myfile.log_*: No such file or directory

-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 0 Sep 26 23:03 ./myfile.log_20150926_1928
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 0 Sep 26 23:03 ./myfile.log_20150926_1926
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 0 Sep 26 23:03 ./myfile.log_20150926_1930
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 0 Sep 26 23:03 ./myfile.log_20150926_1927
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 0 Sep 26 23:03 ./myfile.log_20150926_1929
```

I don't understand why "find" command works and not "ls"

Cheers

Comment: Really this is a question about ls, not programming. [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25655/why-doesnt-this-wildcard-work-the-way-i-expect) has a good description of the behaviour.

Comment: @TZHX It's a question about bash's exact rules for globbing. bash is a programming language so it belongs here.

Comment: @TZHX There's more than Ubuntu. FreeBSD, Solaris, HP-UX, IRIX, Cygwin, any unixoid system has a shell where this question makes sense. I've edited it to no longer be bash specific.

Comment: @Jens I'm aware that Ubuntu isn't the only *nix system out there. I posted a link to the ask ubuntu question because it was the first one I found with a clear explanation of the behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Shell expands the asterisk only when not quoted.

Find expands wildcards in `-name` itself, and you usually have to quote them to prevent the shell from expanding them.

Comment: @zuitje: See Bash manual on [Shell Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) generally and [Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) in particular.